# Jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert this jquery to javascript.Please help

```
$("tr").live('click', function() {

alert("row number: " + $(this).index());

});
```

Comment: download jquery library (unminified) and copy the `live` function (note that live disappeared in 1.7+, so download at max 1.7)

Comment: why you want to use pure javascript? The snippet you given evn if it uses jquery is still javascript

Comment: Maybe because that's all they need and using jQuery is an unnecessary load. Also vanilla JS is always faster. @Ramesh

Comment: @Ramesh I want pure javascript.So please help to convert this to javascript

Comment: Do you have any skills in native js? Because the jQuery selector isn't that easy to reproduce. Did you had a look at the jquery function?

Comment: @pc-shooter I know only javascript.

Comment: @pc-shooter — It's trivial to reproduce so long as you have a modern browser. `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @user3462609 — Which bit of this is causing you problems? There are at least 4 different things this code does. A specific, focused question about one of them would be a better question.

Comment: @CodingAnt you can't use it like that, because elements needn't to be present on DOM when the listener is added. Even, differents browsers needs differents sintaxes (i.e. IE8 = `attachEvent()`)

Comment: @Quentin I want to detect which row of a table is being clicked,Dats it

Comment: @user3462609 — And,  given that you want to remove all the jQuery dependent code from what you have in the question, what have you got so far? If the answer is "nothing", then you really should just go away and learn some basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
var elemm=document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var cnt = 0;
for(var i = 0;i<elemm.length;i++)
{
    elemm[i].onclick = function(){alert("row number: " + ++cnt)}
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRx5u/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7jCq4/)</kbd>

**js**

```
function indexInParent(node) {
    var children = node.parentNode.childNodes;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] == node) return num;
        if (children[i].nodeType == 1) num++;
    }
    return -1;
}

function test(el) {
    alert('row number: ' + indexInParent(el));
}
```

---

in html add

```
<tr onclick="test(this)">
```